# Mongoose promise dont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

My mongoose function ignores promises query and instantly falling to end, without waiting for another steps

```
exports.editProduct = (id, data) => {
  Product.findById(id)
    .then((data) => {
        var imgS3arr = data.img;
        var tempArr = [];
        var i = imgS3arr.length
        while (i--) {
            if (!imgS3arr[i].match(/https:\/\/s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com\/es-shop\//g)) {
                tempArr.push(imgS3arr[i])
                imgS3arr.splice(i, 1)
            }
        }
        return tempArr
    })
    .then((tempArr) => {
        var tempArrS3 = []
        return Promise.all(tempArr.map((img, i) => {
            return fetch.remote(img).then((base) => {
                var buf = Buffer.from(base[0], 'base64');
                var imgS3 = {
                    Key: data.title.replace(/( )|(")/g, "_") + "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2),
                    Body: buf,
                    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
                    ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
                };
                return s3Bucket.putObject(imgS3).promise().then((data) => {
                    tempArrS3.push('https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/es-shop/' + imgS3.Key)
                    console.log(tempArrS3)
                }).catch((err) => {
                    throw err;
                });
            });
        }))
        .then((tempArrS3) => {
          edited.title = data.title;
          edited.img = imgS3arr.concat(tempArrS3);
          return edited
        });
    })
    .then((edited) => {
      console.log(edited)
      return edited.save();
    });
  }
```

[There is a point where I call this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4oIK.png)

I think, I using promises dont right

Can some one help me with this trouble?

Comment: You should have either `return Product.findById(id)` or `(id, data) => Product.findById(id)`, since your outer function definition is not returning a Promise. There is no point returning a Promise from the last item in the chain if the initial call does not `return`.

Comment: Please when you are writing code, especially with javascript. Divide your code into logicial functions. Using callback/promises make it unreadable really fast. You missed some `.catch` tho, which can be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to call `return` statement in `editProduct` function:

```
exports.editProduct = (id, data) => {
  return Product.findById(id);
  ...
```